# knockout: Do not evaluate computed observable on setter

Tags: knockout.js, deferred-execution

Hi i have the following function.

```
function TaxModel() {
    this.amount = ko.observable("");
    this.percentage = ko.observable("");
    this.tax = ko.computed(
        {
            read:function() {
            return this.amount() * this.percentage();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true 
    }, this);
}
```

Now during onload the value should have taxModel.tax be set to 200.00 (the system loaded value).

my html

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.amount, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" id="amount"/>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.percentage, valueUpdate: 'percentage'" id="percent"/>

<input type="text" id="tax" data-bind="value: $data.tax"/>
```

Now when i load the page, I want to set the value initially for the observable but I don't want to compute the value until onchange is made by user.

```
var taxModel = new TaxModel();
taxModel.amount(100.00);
taxModel.percentage(0.0875);

ko.applyBindings(taxModel);
```

Since it is input text user can override the value.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to do this, here's a straightforward albeit not the most elegant way:

```
function TaxModel(initialAMount, initialPercentage) {
    this.amount = ko.observable(initialAMount);
    this.percentage = ko.observable(initialPercentage);
    this.tax = ko.computed(
        {
            read:function() {
              if (this.amount() === initialAmount) { return 200.00; }
              return this.amount() * this.percentage();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true 
    }, this);
}
```

And change the call to the constructor function into:

```
var taxModel = new TaxModel(100.00, 0.0875);
```

Like I said: straightforward though with a few rough edges. For one, the above computed will  return `200.00` also if the user changes back to the exact something equal to `initialAmount`. The question doesn't really mention any requirements on this terrain, and it should be straightforward to change the above into a more elaborate version that has a better `if` condition (for example make `amount` into a writeable computed observable that will set a "changedByUser" flag on first edit).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, I'm not too sure if I like it though. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victoryismine06/RDwqH/)

```
function TaxModel(intAmt, intPer, intTax) {
    var self = this;
    self.amount = ko.observable(intAmt);
    self.percentage = ko.observable(intPer);
    self.tax = ko.observable(intTax);

    self.amount.subscribe(function(newValue){
        self.tax(calcTax());
    });

    self.percentage.subscribe(function(newValue){
        self.tax(calcTax());
    });

    function calcTax(){
        return self.amount() * self.percentage();
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new TaxModel(100,0.0875));
```

Comment: Seems effective. Be careful with this approach though, it may recalculate tax too early. If memory serves me right past versions of KnockoutJS sometimes fire a change for an observable even when there was no actual change (e.g. you put focus to `amount` input and blur wihtout changing anything).

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I decided to do was add initialTax percentage with a field onload

```
if (this.onload()) {
   return this.initialTax
} else {
   // do calculation.
}
```